# Is the same thread used between each task in a AWS step function?

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Suppose I have a step function with only two tasks: start -> task 1 -> task 2 -> end.

Just wonder if the same thread is used in task 1 and task 2.

The scenario is like this. We set some resources at the beginning of a thread execution. Those resources need to be closed ONLY when the thread ends.

So if task 1 and 2 share the same thread, need to close them at the end of task 2. But if not, then need to close the resource in both task 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they don't share a CPU thread. They may not even run on the same underlying server.

Comment: whats the maximum no.of.threads Step Function process in parallel? could you please share any ref if you have?